# XAML Listview scrolling

Tags: xaml, listview, scroll

I have a small problem with scrolling on listview control.

I am trying to turn the scrolling option on when the list on the listview hits the bottom edge of the device. Right now the listview appears on the popup control in my app, I tried settings like binding the height of the listview to the mainpage grid, which didn't work.

Here is the link to the screenshot. The bottom list that is actually the listview control.

[Screenshot](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE2F800193D03193!186162&authkey=!AL_olzAVWK0k96E&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Here is the XAML that has listview and the other controls on a popup control:

```
<Popup x:Name="setShiftPopup" Width="350" Height="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="borderMainPopup" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="#FFE4E4E4" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="2"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF0B6CF8" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,-2,0" CornerRadius="10"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSelectedDatePopup" Grid.Row="0" Margin="21,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFF7F0EF"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="SliderOne" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftStartPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged" Margin="48,26,44,9.5" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftStartStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>

                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="SliderTwo" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftEndPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="48,13.5,44,80.333" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftEndStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Value="48"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Favbutton" Grid.Row="3">
                    <Button x:Name="btnAddToFas" Click="btnAddToFas_Click" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource btnOnPopup}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="4">
                    <ListView x:Name="lvFASList" ItemsSource="{Binding theFasListOC}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="theShift" Text="{Binding theShift}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteShift" Click="btnDeleteShift_Click" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Grid Row that the ListView is in cannot determine a height.

```
<Popup x:Name="setShiftPopup" Width="350" Height="Auto">
    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=setShiftPopup, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=setShiftPopup, Path=Height}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="borderMainPopup" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#FFE4E4E4" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=setShiftPopup}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=setShiftPopup}" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid Margin="8.333,67.333,7.5,7.5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="160.833"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="68.357"/> // Overflowing due to this set of Auto. 
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftStartPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged" Grid.Row="0" Margin="48,26,44,9.5" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftStartStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="1" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftEndPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="48,13.5,44,80.333" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftEndStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Value="48"/>
                <Grid x:Name="gridFASListAndSetButtons" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,85.5,0,-5.31" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/> // This row does not have a set height and it cant be determined from the parent
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnAddToFas" Click="btnAddToFas_Click" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource btnOnPopup}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ListView x:Name="lvFASList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding theFasOC}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <Grid>
                                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="theShift" Text="{Binding theShift}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17"/>
                                  <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnDeleteShift" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=borderMainPopup}" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,-2,0">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0B6CF8"/>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbSelectedDatePopup" Grid.Row="0" Margin="21,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFF7F0EF"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Here is some simplified code that should help, Let me know if you still have problems.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> // For the header
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> // Slider one
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> // Slider two
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> // Favs button
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> // Listview
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0">


    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="SliderOne" Grid.Row="1">


    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="SliderTwo" Grid.Row="2">


    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="Favbutton" Grid.Row="3">


    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="3">
        // Your ListView
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Grids can be put inside each StackPanel or you can swap the StackPanels for grids. This xaml will give you a layout similar to the picture below, The height of each blue cell in the picture will be determined by the accumulative height of the content in each blue StackPanel i.e "Header", "SliderOne", "SliderTwo" and "Favbutton".

StackPanel "ListView" will Fill the remaining space.

[image]

**Update**

@Sumchans Okay I have tired to replicate your problem and it seems that a Popup is not in the same visual tree (someone might be able to correct me on this). You will need to somehow set the height of the 'Popup' to something other than Auto to achieve your desired result.

One way in doing this is by binding the height to your most outer element. Most likely a grid, see below.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyMostOuterControl" >


... <!-- The rest of you controls -->


<Popup x:Name="setShiftPopup" Width="350" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyMostOuterControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="borderMainPopup" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="#FFE4E4E4" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="2"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF0B6CF8" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,0,-2,0" CornerRadius="10"/>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSelectedDatePopup" Grid.Row="0" Margin="21,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FFF7F0EF"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="SliderOne" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftStartPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged" Margin="48,26,44,9.5" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftStartStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>

                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="SliderTwo" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Slider x:Name="sliderShiftEndPopup" ValueChanged="sliderShiftStartEndPopup_ValueChanged"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="48,13.5,44,80.333" Maximum="48" LargeChange="0" SmallChange="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderShiftEndStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Value="48"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="Favbutton" Grid.Row="3">
                    <Button x:Name="btnAddToFas" Click="btnAddToFas_Click" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource btnOnPopup}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="4">
                    <ListView x:Name="lvFASList" ItemsSource="{Binding theFasListOC}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="theShift" Text="{Binding theShift}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteShift" Click="btnDeleteShift_Click" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                             </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Sumchans Can you update your question to show the new code or create a small program that replicates the problem and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks Steveybrown for the detailed explanation. I changed the whole XAML to the one you have mentioned here. It made the code a lot more neater and readable, but it didn't solve my issue. The listviews height still keeps crossing the bottom edge of the screen, which is what my main issue was. The sliders are like locked into the position. You can move it by putting a specific number, but when I tried dragging it to the point I want, it didn't allow me. I am thinking about different about different screen sizes here, that's why I didn't want to put in a specific number to each setting.

Comment: Also I am trying to set the popup to the center on load, and also maintain the center position even when it grows.

Comment: I have updated the code, in order to center the popup to an element you can use [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) If this doesn't work please can you provide a small program which reproduces the problem and I'll have a look.

Comment: Is it ok, if I give you the whole work in progress. There is only one XAML file.   https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EE2F800193D03193!188684&authkey=!AF9WD9mauavlq68&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from you not setting the proper height to your listview. You said you tried giving it the height of your Mainpage when your listview is in a popup ?

If the listview is in the popup you need to give it the height of the popup. If not, it will be too big and you wont be able to access the last elements.

Also I notice that your listview is part of a row. Let's say that your popup has a height of 1200 and the 4 first rows of your stackpanel total a height of 600. Your listview (and consequently the last row) will **need** to have a height of 600 or less.

You need to figure out the exact height needed for your listview. In this case, since your row has a height of "*" I would suggest doing something like this :

```
<Grid x:Name = "GridListView" Grid.Row = "4">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ListView">
        <ListView x:Name="lvFASList" ItemsSource="{Binding theFasListOC}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="40" Grid.Row="1" Height ="{Binding ElementName=GridListView, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="theShift" Text="{Binding theShift}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDeleteShift" Click="btnDeleteShift_Click" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Pretty much make it possible for you to get the height of the grid in which the listview is (this is why you put the stackpanel in a new grid `<Grid Grid.Row ="4" x:Name="GridListView"`). Then set the height correspondingly `Height="{Binding ElementName=GridListView, Path=ActualHeight}"`

Comment: Hi micbobo, I tried your code, now what happens is the listview doesn't expand at all. It is just locked to a fixed height.

Comment: Yes I thought that that was what you wanted. A listview taking the entire Row 4 being able to scroll down the items ? Also why is it that the listview is affected to the row 1 when the stackpanel it is situated in is in the row 4 @Sumchans ?

Comment: Hi micbobo, I just added the maxheight property to the listview, which will be ok for now. My intention was to center the popup which has the listview, and also keep it centered even when it gets bigger with data. I really appreciate the detailed explanation.